# Create and allocate a pointer inside struct C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, interop

I am facing the following issue.
I have a C++ API passed to C# through DLL. Here is how the api looks like:

```
header.h

extern "C"  __declspec( dllexport) bool f(CustomClass* myclass);
```

where:

```
struct CustomClass
{
    double* grades;
    int* ages;
    char name[16];
}
```

So I intend to call this f from C# and face difficulties to allocate the pointers:
To be more precise, I can allocate the CustomClass* but cannot the underlying types:

```
struct CustomClass
{
    public unsafe char* name;
    public unsafe double* grades;
    public unsafe int* ages;
};

fixed(CustomClass* instances = new CustomClass[5]) //  this is fine
{
    instances[0].grades = new double[10];// no good, , cannot implicitly convert from double[] to double*
    fixed(instances[0].grades = new double[10]) // no good, instances is a variable but used as a type
    {
    }
}
```

Can anyone help to understand how to allocate a pointer inside a class?
Or maybe any other workaround to satisfy the C++ DLL api?

Comment: You want to allocate an array of doubles - not allocate a pointer

Comment: Does C# have C-style arrays? If so, shouldn't `name` be `public char name[16];` in C#? Also, shouldn't the members be in the same order in C# as in the C++ class?

Comment: Where is it defined how big `grades` and `ages` are to be, if they are C arrays?

Comment: lets suppose size if agreed on both C++ and C# sides, I need to allocate and pass to C++, C++ must fill in data

Comment: Have you ever looked at C++ cli for interoperability between C++ and .Net? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170
Its much more robust then using pinvoke "C" style calls since you have  much better and clearer control over memory managment (don't forget C++ and C# have a totally different view on that)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the struct using fixed-size arrays. Fill in the necessary size for each

```cs
struct CustomClass
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    double[] grades = new double[10];

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    int[] ages = new int[10];

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    char[] name = new char[16];
}
```